# Install Python package before running NodeJS application on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a NodeJS application I'm running successfully on Elastic Beanstalk. But for 1 particular script I need to execute a command which uses the Couchapp Python library, like so:

```
exec( 'couchapp push somefile someurl' );
```

I want to install this requirement before staring the server with pip, potentially even in a virtualenv in which the NodeJS application starts as well. What's the best way of doing this, since I'm running a NodeJS EB environment?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `packages` directive in an Elastic Beanstalk configuration file. Full documentation can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages) but I believe it'd look something like this:

**.ebextensions/01-install-couchapp.config**

```
packages:
  python:
    couchapp: []
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. deploy failed